# UITableView Content Offset Increasing Unexpectedly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, offset

I have a UITableView embedded in a navigation controller. When i segue from the TableView onto the next screen, i store the offset such that if i press the 'back' button, the offset on the original view remains the same, and it doesnt scroll up to the top.

```
var tableViewContentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableView.contentOffset = tableViewContentOffset
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    tableViewContentOffset = tableView.contentOffset
}
```

This works perfectly when the view loads the first time, however each time i move onto the next screen and then return, the offset is increased by y(-64.0)
What is causing this?
First time loaded:
[image]

After Segueing and returning once:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set `automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInsets` to `false`.

Comment: This doesn't fix the fact that the offset is constantly shifting down